# JPA Hibernate Clildren with @EmbeddedId not loadded on Weblogic server but loadded in integration test

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with JPA and Hibernate where I have 2 entities that are in relation of 1 to many.
On local host on the integraiton test using H2 the things are as they should (children are loaded), when deployed into the weblogic server that is using Oracle as DB, the children are not loaded.
Any idea on this?
The entities definitions are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_MASTER")
@Data
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Case implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1919288768119684307463L;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 55)
 private String id;
 @Column(name = "CODE_ADR", nullable = false, length = 100)

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "id.masterId")
 @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
 private Set<MasterReference> references = new TreeSet<>();

}
```

The EmbeddedId class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class MasterReferenceId implements Serializable, Comparable {
 @ManyToOne(optional = false)
 @JoinColumn(name = "MASTER_ID", nullable = false)
 @ToString.Exclude
 @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
 private Master masterId;

 @Column(name = "REF", nullable = false, length = 42)
 private String reference;

 @Column(name = "SHORCUT", nullable = false, length = 100)
 private String shortcut;

 @Column(name = "REF_DATE")
 private Date refDate;

 @Column(name = "REF_BACK", length = 1)
 @Convert(converter = BooleanToNumberConverter.class)
 private Boolean refBack;

 @Column(name = "REF_DATA_ROW", length = 2000)
 private String refDataRow;

 @Override
 public int compareTo(Object o) {
     if (o instanceof MasterReferenceId && ((MasterReferenceId) o).getReference() != null && ((MasterReferenceId) o).getReference() != null) {
        return ((MasterReferenceId) o).getReference().compareTo(this.getReference());
    }
     return 0;
 }
}
```

The cild entity:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "TB_MASTER_REFERENCE")
 @Data
 @ToString
 @NoArgsConstructor
 public class MasterReference implements Serializable, Comparable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -517596820344348395356L;

  @EmbeddedId
  private MasterReferenceId id;

  @Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE", nullable = false)
  private Date updateDate;


  @Column(name = "COMMENTS", length = 4000)
  private String comments;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof MasterReference && ((MasterReference) o).getId() != null) {
        return ((MasterReference) o).getId().compareTo(this.getId());
    }
    return 0;
  }
 }
```

Comment: You should not put references in an embeddedID - ID classes can only contain basic mappings.

Comment: @Chris then why it is working on integration tests, but it is nto working when deployed on the weblogic server?

Comment: Did you try it? What you have isn't supported by the spec, so you'll need to turn on logging to find out why the behaviour is different. Why would you want to have to instantiate an instance of Master to build a key just to be able to call em.find for your MasterReference instances? You mentioned weblogic though - Spring does some non-spec compliant JPA behaviour and might operate differently within Weblogic where it has a chance to load the persistence unit first.

Comment: @Chris yes I am trying it now and see what are the results. I'll come nack with the results

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
public class MasterReference implements Serializable, Comparable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private MasterReferenceId id;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "MASTER_ID", nullable = false)
  @MapsId("masterId")
  private Master masterId;

  ..
}

public class MasterReferenceId implements Serializable, Comparable {

  private String masterId;
  ..
}
```

Change the mappedBy in the OneToMany on references to just "masterId" so that it uses the reference mapping instead of trying to use the embeddedId.

Comment: the master_id column is part of the composed PK in TB_MASTER_REFERENCE, so i cant exclude it form the embedable class. Or you suggest to put the normal column there and the extra mapping in the the class, but that would require to put on it updatable false and inserable false. Which is nto ok. I guess a better way is to use IdClass instead of Embedable. But I am testing it now the both ways and will see the results

Comment: Try the code- mapsId is for this type of mapping, telling JPA the Basic ID mapping needs to be set using the fk value from the reference. No need for updatable/insertable, you just need to set the reference and the ID value is set by JPA.

Comment: I tried, and it did not work. The problem is that on the weblogic server there is an older version of hibernate. The change that worked was to simplify the model and eliminate the  EmbeddedId and do it more simple. More preciselly eliminate the FK from the EmbeddedId